# Different SVG layouts in each device

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a web layout built from few SVG elements(polygons and rectangles). 
I would like to have separate set of SVG code for the screen size max. 768 px width and max. 420 px width. 
Anybody here tried to have separate sets of SVG graphics for different devices? Any advices how to render different SVG based on the device screen sizes? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css media queries to do this. Here's a [blogpost](http://timkadlec.com/2013/04/media-queries-within-svg/) with some examples.

Example:

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
            @media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
                #slogan{
                    display: none;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <g id="slogan">
        ...
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Super - it works! Thanks a lot Erik. I also found that it is best for me to exactly specify the media querie px range(min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) so I could easier navigate through blocks of svg code.